# JSDoc: how to refer a returned of invoked function directly into another function

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have following function:

```
function carModel() {
    return {
        brand: "NIO",
        model: "ET5"
    }
}
```

I need refer a returned of `carModel()` into another function:

```
/**
 * @returns {carModel}
 */
function another() {
    //some unpredictable code but returned as invoked carModel()
}
```

But I can't using another function by JSDoc as expected, need extra `()` like this to work:

```
another()().brand
```

I need call another function by JSDoc like this:

```
another().brand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using TypeScript to check JSDoc you can use [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility type for this purpose

```js
function carModel() {
  return {
    brand: "NIO",
    model: "ET5"
  };
};

/**
 * @returns {ReturnType<carModel>}
 */
function another() {
  return carModel();
}

another().brand;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are encountering this issue is due to the fact that you are returning the carModel function instead of its result.

```
const returnedFunc = another();
returnedFunc().model;
```

When you call the another() function, what is returned is actually another function. To access the brand property, you need to call the returned function again.

If you want to directly access the object, it is necessary to return the result of the carModel function when it is called.

```
type CarType = {
  brand: string,
  model: string
}
/**
 * @returns {CarType}
 */
function another() {
    //some unpredictable code but returned as invoked carModel()

    // Currently, what is happening is that the `CarModel` function is being returned.  
    // return CarModel

    // To access the intended result, it is necessary to return the result of the `CarModel` function when it is called.
    return CarModel();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, in your case we need declare car type first then use it as return type in JSDoc and maybe only work in TypeScript file.

So I think we can't refer the returned invoked some function directly as return type in JSDoc.